# Mobile Testing tool-> Android Native application

Tags: android, testing, mobile

Hi Dudes as i am testing Android mobile Native application can anybody shoot your update  about testing tool to test

Answer (score 1):

I prefer ROBOTIUM to test the native applications ,check these links

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials

http://www.stepinforum.org/hyderabad_conference_2011/tutorials/kishore_sandeep.html

http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=robotium.pdf&pbx=1&oq=robotium.pdf&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=243l1450l1l2578l3l4l0l0l0l0l200l554l1.2.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=af657eb7a9945641&biw=1360&bih=644

Comment: Thanks Raghu its a very good tool...

Comment: k then accept the answer

Comment: Sure Raghu Am in study of this tool..

Answer (score 0):

Try using bot-bot.

http://imaginea.github.com/bot-bot/

Its an open-source Native android application with record and replay features.